# Backgroungeolocation engage ionic3

Tags: background, geolocation, ionic3

I'm using [mauron85 Backgroundgeolocation plugin](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) for my ionic 3 application.

It works, the only problem is the timing when it engage.

The problem is even if I subscribe and start the plugin, it engage only after a couple of minutes.

Namely it returns the position in the moment that I start it, but before engaging and actively tracking it takes some time.

Also sometime when I put the app in background it does not start recording.

That is the code I used:

```
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';
```

Then the consifugration and start:

```
        let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
        locationProvider: 0,
        desiredAccuracy: 10,
        stationaryRadius: 1,
        distanceFilter: 1,
        activitiesInterval: 100,
        interval: 1000,
        notificationTitle: 'TiCaccio is tracking you',
        notificationText: 'you know it, right?'
        // debug: true
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

        console.log("Background location", location);
        this.lat = location.latitude;
        this.lng = location.longitude;
});
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

Now the problem is in fact that sometimes it engage, sometimes not. And even when it engage it just do that after a couple of minutes.